# What's the term of what I need to fix here - Umlaut dots missing at 80% zoom?

Tags: typography, font-design

In my font, the Umlaut character is broken when viewing at 80% zoom in Word. It displays like `U` but is in fact `Ü`:

> [image: Missing Umlaut at 80% zoom in Word]

I'm now looking for the correct term of what needs to be fixed. First I thought the font needs *kerning*, but it seems that's only for distances between letters.

I only need the name of the problem. I can then google for the rest.

From the comments it seems the question is unclear, so again in other words: I don't want to fix it in Word - I could just zoom to 100%. I want to fix it in the font by using an aspect or process of typography.

Comment: I'm not sure that is adjustable on Word. Are you editing your own font with another software?

Comment: Imho, this is just a displaying issue caused by Word. I wouldn't care that much... Now, you can try adding a small space before your paragraph, it can solve the issue...

Comment: Could anything overlap over the Ü-Points? Could it be the height of the line?  Or the line itself is so small that the points are cropped?

Comment: I read this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291353/some-characters-missing-or-cut-off-when-displayed-on-screen-in-word Interesting enough it says: "The zoom percentage that the document is set to may cause characters to have the top or bottom portion of the screen font cut off. You can adjust the zoom percentage from 75 percent to 100 percent in most cases to correct this visually." ^^

Answer (score 1):

After more research I think the term I was looking for is [*hinting* [Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting).

It says

> [...] adjust the display of an outline font so that it lines up with a rasterized grid [...]

and I think that's what might happen to the dots of the Umlaut: the just get anti-aliased away.

Hinting might give additional instructions to the dots so that they remain visible. I never did this before and I might need some training, but I can now learn about hinting, apply it to the font and see whether that also has a positive impact on zooming in Word.

It might still not help with zooming, because zooming a 12pt font at 80% may still not use the hinting of a 9.6pt font (12pt*80%). Discussing this is probably worth its own question.

Comment: It could work (though I think @Vinny could be on to something), but why worry about how Word displays fonts? For me Word is just for writing. It is not used to display the final result anyway. Or?

Comment: @Wolff: if my font looks ugly in Word, people might refrain from using it, so testing my font in Word is one of my tasks.

Comment: Oh, you never said that it was your own design. Then it makes sense.

Comment: @Wolff: indeed. In the question I said "a font". That's probably also the source of all those comments. I changed it in the question. Thanks for pointing that out. Small word, big difference. I didn't notice it.

Comment: Verify that your bounding box wasn't affected by the font-size change for that character?